# How to get a value as number from Mongodb, casbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I have a simple code for getting the port number from MongoDB. I use scala and the driver is of course casbah.

```
  def getPortNo : Int {
    val query = MongoDBObject("_id" -> "Store")
    val data  = coll.findOne(query)
    return data.get("port")
  }
```

Here my application only has one document that id is equal to "store".

but this is not resolved in IDE.

I have the same code for getting the version.

```
  def getVersion : String = {
    val query = MongoDBObject("_id" -> "Store")
    val data  = coll.findOne(query)
    return data.get("version").toString
  }
```

this works well.

I tried `data.get("port").toString.toInt` and It also does not work.

Can someone tell me how to do this. I think the problem here is the returning value in not either number or a string. what is the return type and how can I cast it into a number.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you store "port" field. Try `data.as[Number]("value").intValue()`. It must work any number format.

And you should consider that `findOne` returns `Option`, so you can return `Option` too:

```
  def getPortNo : Option[Int] = {
    val query = MongoDBObject("_id" -> "Store")
    val data  = coll.findOne(query)
    data.map(_.as[Number]("port").intValue)
  }
```

Or use some default value:

```
  def getPortNo : Int = {
    val query = MongoDBObject("_id" -> "Store")
    val data  = coll.findOne(query)
    data.map(_.as[Number]("port").intValue).getOrElse(80)
  }
```

Comment: did you `import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._`?

Comment: yes.
here are the import statements I have imported other relevant to casbah.
import com.mongodb.casbah.MongoClient
and 
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

Comment: Oh, I'm forget that `findOne` returns `Option`. I updated my answer.